# sql server trigger gives an error in column names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a trigger on a table in SQL Server 2014, but it is giving an error like below

> Invalid column name 'MemberID'

The query I am executing is

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.EDIT_CASH_BOX_TREGER
ON dbo.CASH_BOX
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                         AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)-- Set Action to Updated.
BEGIN 
 
   UPDATE dbo.CASH_BOX
     SET CASH_BOX.CASH_NAME='CANCEL NEW MEMBER '+INSERTED.MemberID
   ,  CASH_BOX.CASH_AMOUNT=INSERTED.NetAmount
    ,  CASH_BOX.CASH_REMARKS='CANCEL INSERT NEW MEMBER'
    ,  CASH_BOX.UPDATED_BY=INSERTED.UpdatedBy
    ,  CASH_BOX.UPDATED=GETDATE()
    ,  CASH_BOX.USER_ID=INSERTED.UpdatedBy
    ,  CASH_BOX.ACTIVE=1
    ,  CASH_BOX.OPERATION='CANCEL'
  FROM
        INSERTED
   WHERE (CASH_BOX.CASH_NAME=('NEW MEMBER '+INSERTED.MemberID)) AND  CASH_BOX.CASH_AMOUNT=INSERTED.NetAmount
END
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)-- Set Action to Insert.
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CASH_BOX (CASH_NAME, CASH_AMOUNT, CASH_REMARKS, INSERTED_BY, INSERTED_DATE, USER_ID, ACTIVE,OPERATION)VALUES
    ('NEW MEMBER '+INSERTED.MemberID,INSERTED.NetAmount,'NEW MEMBER',INSERTED.UpdatedBy ,INSERTED.Updated,INSERTED.UpdatedBy,1,'ADD')
END
  END 

;
```

Comment: Also, why if this trigger on `DELETE` when it never references `deleted`? This feels like the trigger is part of a larger [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), if I am honest.

Comment: The problem is in your `IF EXISTS` portion of the `TRIGGER`. You use `VALUES`, and then reference `INSERTED.MemberID`. `MemberID` has not context there. You need to use `INSERT INTO...SELECT ... FROM...` syntax. This, however, does not change my above comment.

Comment: In fact, why is there even a `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)` in there? The only time `inserted` would contain no rows is on a `DELETE`, and you do nothing in the event of a `DELETE` in the above, and inside the `IF` you only reference `inserted`.

Comment: Why would an after-insert trigger insert additional rows into the same table on which it is defined? And your logic is mostly likely faulty since both blocks of code (i.e., the update block and the insert block) would be executed for an update. As Larnu states - this seems to be a path to the wrong destination.  And it appears you rely on implicit conversion - a bad habit you should avoid.